# How do I assign -0x80000000 to long long variable in VS2019?

Tags: visual-studio, c++17, 64-bit, signed, negative-integer

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community edition. I have the following C++ code snippet:

```
long long l = 0x80000000;
assert(l > 0); //true
l = -0x7fffffff;
assert(l < 0); // true
l = -0x80000000;
assert(l < 0); // FALSE
```

I expect `-0x80000000` to end up sign-extended to 64-bit value of 0xFFFFFFFF80000000 but it doesn't. Instead it carries the positive 0x80000000 value. What do I miss?

Comment: Try `l = -0x80000000LL;`

Comment: That does the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) for integral literals without suffixes.

In short, `0x80000000`'s type [is `unsigned int`](https://godbolt.org/z/3qvPeT) because it's an hexadecimal number bigger than `int`'s max value. In order to make it long long, you must add the `LL` suffix, i.e. `0x80000000LL`.

Comment: Correct for Visual Studio. Other implementations could have other maximum values for `int`, but 32 bits is by far the most common size today.